# How to populate object props in pug mixin?

Tags: javascript, pug, mixins

So i have this mixin:

```
mixin slider({classes: {slider, arrows, arrow, dots, dot}, useArrows = false, useDots = false, dotsCounter}, sliderSettings)
  div(class=['slider', slider].join(' '))
    .glide__track(data-glide-el="track")
      ul.glide__slides
        block
    if useArrows
      div(class=arrows, data-glide-el="controls")
        span(class=['arrow-left', arrow].join(' '), data-glide-dir="<<")
          +icon({name: 'angle-left'})
        span(class=['arrow-right', arrow].join(' '), data-glide-dir=">>")
          +icon({name: 'angle-right'})
    if useDots
      div(class=['slider-dots', dots].join(' '), data-glide-el="controls[nav]")
        while i < dotsCounter
          span(class=['slider-dot', dot].join(' '), data-glide-dir="=" + i++)

  script new Glide('.#{slider}', #{sliderSettings}).mount()
```

As a second param of my mixin i'm passing sliderSettings, that is an object with props, that i need to pas in script tag at the end of the code. If i'm using `#{sliderSettings}`, i'm getting `[object Object]` in html code of the page, but i need to get populated object with it's props.

Is it possible to get what i want?

Answer (score 1):

So i found an answer. I need to improve this line:

```
script new Glide('.#{slider}', #{sliderSettings}).mount()
```

to this:

```
script new Glide('.#{slider}', !{JSON.stringify(sliderSettings)}).mount()
```